# Looking for a word for being in multiple places at the same time (not bilocate)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I cannot recall a word I used to use 20 years ago that meant being able to be in 2 or more places at the same time.  Bilocate is the only word that comes to mind, but that's not it. This is not astral projection or remote viewing. It's physically being able to accomplish things in multiple locations at the same time. The thesauruses and online sites gave me no synonyms for bilocate. Maybe I'm thinking of a phrase and not just a single word. Any suggestions?

SAMPLE USAGE: I wish there were several clones of me. Then I could ____ and get everything done.

Comment: There is a difference between being an _influence_ in many locations and actually _existing_ in many locations, simultaneously. Humans are confined to just one location of, approximately, a few feet by one or two (or possibly even more) feet.

Comment: What's wrong with *bilocate* or *multilocate* other than they are not the word you can't remember? They otherwise seem like perfect answers.

Answer (score 2):

> **[omnipresent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/omnipresent)**: (adjective ) ​ present or having an effect everywhere at the same time:
>
> *The singer became an omnipresent icon of style and beauty.*

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneity? "Duality" is used in physics, although actually being in two places at once is not possible, things occuring at the same time are simultaneous. Ubiquity means occuring everywhere, quotidian means occurring daily, although people use it (wrongly) to mean constantly.

Looking at your sample sentence, it's closer to 'duplicate' or 'replicate'

If you wanted to create a neologism, you could do a word play like "omni-present" (emphasis on last syllable) or "ubiquitize"

Maybe "pluralize?"

Comment: I like pluralize: I could pluralize myself.

Answer (score 1):

[**Bifurcate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bifurcate) (intransitive verb):

> to divide into two branches or parts · The stream bifurcates into two
>   narrow channels.

(Although, for that to fit into your example sentence, it should really read "I wish I had the ability to clone myself. Then I could bifurcate and get everything done.")

Marvel Comics' [Multiple Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox) has the ability to create duplicates of himself in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

"Then I could *be ubiquitous* and get everything done."

See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ubiquitous).

I now see that someone above has mentioned this, but the definition does seem to meet the criteria. It is not a verb, obviously, but it works as an adjective.

Answer (score -3):

I wish there were several clones of me. Then I could be **here, there, and everywhere** and get everything done.  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/everywhere)