# Looking for a word for being in multiple places at different time

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

So I am writing content for a health care company, (Doctor's Profiles) they did provide the content but I want it to be a bit professional. So Here's an example but I want the opposite of this. English is not my first language so can't think of a word that would be used here.

> Dr. John practices as a Neonatologist at Hospital A and Hospital B and
> charges $500 and $600 respectively.

Now if the doctor has the same price at both locations what will be the word that would replace "**respectively**"?

> Dr. John practices as a Neonatologist at the hospital a and hospital b
> and charges $500 -word-.

I read this article [Looking for a word for being in multiple places at the same time (not bilocate)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445946/looking-for-a-word-for-being-in-multiple-places-at-the-same-time-not-bilocate) but I don't think it applies to my situation.

Comment: Well you could finish the second sentence with *at each location* or you could finish it with a full stop immediately after *$500*.  And, in case this is not obvious, any word you are looking for has nothing to do with the doctor being in two places at once.  Unless Dr John has supernatural abilities Dr John practices neonatology in different places at different times.

Comment: Dr john practices at different places at different times, not two places at once. let's say he practices 3 days of the week at hospital a and 2 days of the week in hospital b on weekends he takes a break.

Comment: and as I said I want it to be a bit professional, otherwise I could have even finished the first sentence just like you advised each location instead of writing respectively.

Comment: here you go sir, sorry about that I fixed it.

Comment: There's nothing 'unprofessional' about either of the suggestions in my first comment.  Reaching into the English language's enormity of rarely-used words for replacements for commonly-used words doesn't make writing 'professional', it makes writing turgid and dense, and hard to understand.  But that's it, no more commentary from me.

Comment: No one is going to think the doctor practices simultaneously in two places, unless this is science fiction.